# Android two-way databinding, textview not updating

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to use MVVM pattern with android databinding.
I have an edittext and a textview that should show the same text when I type in the edittext field by binding to the model via the observablefield with a LocationType model object.

From testing both fields are set to "hello" when I start the app, as expected.
But when I type in the edittextfield the textview does not update, even tough the model object gets updated correctly as can be seen with by debug.

When I use an:

```
observablefield<String>
```

drop using the model and just set to some text and update the xml to use this field. It works as intended.

**model:**

```
public class LocationType {
private String locationType;

public String getLocationType() {
   return locationType;
}

public void setLocationType(String locationType) {
  this.locationType = locationType;

 }
}
```

**modelView**:

```
public class LocationTypeViewModel extends BaseObservable {
  @Bindable
  private    ObservableField<LocationType> locationTypeObservableField = new ObservableField<>();
  private Context context;
  LocationType locationType;

  public LocationTypeViewModel(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    locationType = new LocationType();
    locationType.setLocationType("Hello");
    locationTypeObservableField.set(locationType);


  }

  public ObservableField<LocationType> getLocationTypeObservableField() {
    Log.d("CALLED GET", locationType.getLocationType());
    return locationTypeObservableField;
  }


}
```

**XML:**

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <import type="android.view.View"/>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="fragment.LocationType.viewmodel.LocationTypeViewModel"/>
</data>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@{viewModel.locationTypeObservableField.locationType}"
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@{viewModel.locationTypeObservableField.locationType}"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        />




</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 3):

android:text="@={viewModel.locationTypeObservableField.locationType}"

You forgot to add "=" .check and compare above line with your code.

Comment: omg! I just knew that "=" is required. non of the articles told me this.

Answer (score 2):

Two way databinding should be like this
  android:text="@={ProfileViewModel.mobileNumber}"
**You forgot to add "="**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are observing changes to the field inside `LocationTypeViewModel` which points to a `LocationType` object. That will only notify changes when the object reference changes. What you want is an observer on the actual `String` field.

You are also missing an important two-binding symbol on your `EditText`. You want to use `@={obj.fieldName}` instead of `@{obj.fieldName}`. The @= signals that you want changes to propagate back to the source.

Here is your code edited to work as intended:

```
public class LocationType {

    private String location;

    public LocationType(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}

public class LocationTypeViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    private final LocationType locationType;

    public LocationTypeViewModel() {
        locationType = new LocationType("Hello");
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getLocation() {
        return locationType.getLocation();
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        locationType.setLocation(location);
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.location);
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View"/>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type=".LocationTypeViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@={viewModel.location}"
            android:id="@+id/edittext1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/edittext1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@{viewModel.location}"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had the @= before don't know how it got lost. But how can I have the model as a POJO ?

Comment: You can have the LocationType object extend BaseObservable, then when a field changes that should be observed you need to notify the correct id from the BR generated class. Check out Observable Objects in the docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html. There is a relative example there.

Comment: I see, is that okey to do when designing for MVVM pattern? In most examples the Viewmodel is the one extending BaseObservable.

Comment: Make your viewmodel be a wrapper for your plain pojo, and expose only what you need to. Adding edit for you.

Comment: Thank you for your time! One last question. What do I do if I have more than a string in locationType model? What if i add a string field postalCode and want to observe that aswell?