# Android Conditional string in Textview with databinding not being evaluated

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-databinding

I have now scavenged the web without finding a solution for this problem of mine.

My problem is that I have a `TextView` and in it I would like to display text using the `android:text` attribute. This text should be fetched from `@string` in a conditional manner depending on what `FLAVOR` is running.

I have wrapped my xml layout file in `<layout></layout>` tags and just inside these tags I have imported some classes:

```
 <data>
    <import type="esy.es.matmatt.pidroCounter.BuildConfig"/>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
</data>
```

To conditionally display different text in a Textview depending on FLAVOR I have the following TextView:

```
<TextView
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals(`free`) ? @string/about_text : @string/about_textPro)}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewFree"
        android:layout_below="@+id/aboutTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:autoLink="email"
        android:textColorLink="@color/textn"/>
```

I dont know why this just outputs a blank TextView... It displays neither one...

I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640618/android-two-way-databinding-textview-not-updating) post that I should have a **=** sign after the *@* but when I added that, I just got a compilation error instead:

```
M:\Git Repositories\PidroCounter\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\freeDebug\out\esy\es\matmatt\pidroCounter\DataBinderMapperImpl.java:10: error: cannot find symbol import esy.es.matmatt.pidroCounter.databinding.FragmentAboutBindingImpl;
                                          ^
```

I cannot simply find the error. The import and conditional syntax I use seems to work fine on visibility of adviews but not at all on TextViews? I have no clue what I am doing wrong. Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Actually I now realized the conditions don't work in adviews either (XML). The reason I thought it was because I conditonally load `MobileAds` programmatically too...

Answer (score 1):

I think that your issue is present in the binding expression you have written due to use of `String.valueOf`.
It should be

```
android:text="@{BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals(`free`) ? @string/about_text : @string/about_textPro}"
```

In case this doesn't work, please open the `BindingImpl.java` (E.g: `YourLayoutNameBindingImpl.java`) class generated by databinding. Search for your view Id (`textViewFree`) and post that generated code here.